# How to get multiple rows based on max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table SalePrices in SQL server and data same as below:

```
SPID        ProductID       Price       Date
001         Pro01           10        2016-03-10
002         Pro01           20        2016-03-11
003         Pro02           10        2016-03-13
004         Pro02           20        2016-03-15
```

What I want is create a view that show only one ProductID and Price that I have modified at the last time. So what I want is same as the result below:

```
ProductID   Price   Date
Pro01       20      2016-03-11
Pro02       20      2016-03-15
```

Answer (score 2):

There're few different approaches for this, for example, using `row_number()`:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        ProductID, Price, Date,
        row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by Date desc) as rn
    from <Table>
)
select
    ProductID, Price, Date
from cte
where
    rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d851/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Another version with windowing functions, this one with [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx);

```
SELECT ProductID, price, date 
FROM products
WHERE spid IN (
  SELECT FIRST_VALUE(spid) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY date DESC) spid 
  FROM products
)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6be99/9).

Note that Roman's version with `ROW_NUMBER` should work from SQL Server 2005 and newer, while this will only work for SQL Server 2012 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
    SELECT 
         ProductID
     ,   Price 
     , Date FROM tablename  AS A 
 JOIN (SELECT ProductID,MAX(Date) AS DATE FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY ProductID
) AS B ON A.Date=B.DATE AND A.ProductID=B.ProductID
```

Comment: this will work, but only if there're no duplicate dates per ProductID in the table. Of course, it's not clear what should we show in case of duplications anyway, but just for info

Answer (score 0):

one more approach...

```
select productid,price,date
from 
table t1
where date=(select max(date) from table t2 where t1.productid=t2.productid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last record will have the highest SPID:

```
select 
  ProductId, Price, Date
from
  SalePrices sap
where
  sap.spid =(
  select
    max(sap2.spid)
  from
    SalePrices sap2
  where
    sap2.productId = sap.productId)
```

This query will give u desired result:

```
ProductID   Price   Date
Pro01       20      2016-03-11
Pro02       20      2016-03-15
```

Comment: No window functions, and no problem if several records have the same date, last record will be considered by max SPID grouped by productID